# .Net Core 7 upgrade causes MS Graph to error on IDriveItemChildrenCollectionPage could not be found

Tags: .net-7.0, microsoft-graph-sdks

We are trying to upgrade our .Net core web application to .Net 7 and I am runing into issues with MS Graph. I have updated MS Graph to the latest version, 5.35, but I am still getting errors about the type or namespace not being found for:

IDriveItemChildrenCollectionPage
ISiteDrivesCollectionPage

This also seems to be effecting some of the graph commands, such as:

```
return await _graphServiceClient.Sites[siteId].Drives.Request().GetAsync();
```

The "Request()" part of the line above shows the red squigilly line, and the error "'ChildrenRequestBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Request'".

I can't seem to find any solutions to these problems. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In SDK v5, the method `Request()` has been removed, so you can call `GetAsync()` directly.

```
return await _graphServiceClient.Sites[siteId].Drives.GetAsync();
```

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#removal-of-request-from-the-fluent-api